# PHP distribute percentage based on total numbers

Tags: php

I'm trying to distribute 100% to total numbers (not equally), it can be done manually but I'm looking for a automatically way in PHP. I had to open calculator and get it done for manual.

What I'm trying to achieve is the result similar to this:

```
$value = 10000;
$total_numbers = 9 
$a1 = $value*0.2;
$a2 = $value*0.175;
$a3 = $value*0.15;
$a4 = $value*0.125;
$a5 = $value*0.1;
$a6 = $value*0.08;
$a7 = $value*0.07;
$a8 = $value*0.05;
$a9 = $value*0.04;
```

So as you can see, the first variables have more quantity than the later ones, but if you add these, it will be **1** which is **100%**. So lets say I have `total_numbers=20` then I'll have to re-write it and get a calculator and do it the hard way to accomplish my goal. Is there any way this can be done automatically with a function where I can just tell the total number and it can distribute it to proportions or something?

The first one will always be bigger than rest, then second one bigger than rest but smaller than first, third one being greater than rest but small than first and second, and so on.

Comment: Do you want it to be distributed in some pattern? Or just randomly?

Comment: will the code mentioned above works? or is it not working?

Comment: @NijrajGelani the proportions can be random, but the first 50%- 60% of the total numbers(e.g. 9, so 5~) should have the most of the value then after this the later can be low but again the previous ones will always be bigger than the current (like a6 is set to xx, this will mean that a6 will always be bigger than a7+a8...a(n) but it will always be smaller than a1,a2...a5)

Comment: @AdarshMohan The way I did was manually, I declared each value by myself manually by getting a calculator and adding the value to get pure 1

Comment: so what you are need is a sequence?

Comment: @AdarshMohan a function where I can input the total numbers and it can distribute the 100% of a value into total numbers. So if the total number is 20, then the 100% of a value should be distributed into 20 parts, the 1st one being the biggest, second one being the second biggest and so on.. and if we add all those 20 then it should sum up to 100% of the assigned value.

Comment: How about if you need 200 numbers, you radomly generate 199 unique numbers between x and y. Calculate the total of these numbers and set number 200 to the missing value to complete 100%. Rearrange them from large to small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```php
function distributeValue($value, $num) {
    $parts = $num * ($num + 1) / 2;

    $values = [];
    for ($i = $num; $i > 1; --$i) {
        $values[] = round($value * $i / $parts);
    }

    $values[] = $value - array_sum($values);

    return $values;
}

var_dump(distributeValue(10000, 9));
```

This works by calculating the `$num`th triangle number (the number you get by adding all the numbers from 1 to `$num`) and dividing the total value up into this number of parts.

It then starts by taking `$num` parts, then `$num-1` parts and so on.

Since it's rounding the numbers, the last step is to take the total minus all the other values which is around one part. If you are fine with getting floats instead of ints out, then you can remove the `$values[] = $value - array_sum($values);` line and change the condition of the `for` loop to `$i > 0`.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted!